# Multiple Connections to SQLite Dapper

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, sqlite, dapper

I am using Dapper with my SQLite database. I have developed some multi-threaded code where each thread performs some read and write operations using Dapper ORM. Both the thread may very much try to concurrently write on the same table as well.

The confusion I am facing is that do I have to implement some technique in my code to make the concurrent reads thread safe or do dapper will handle that for me.

**Do note I am familiar that SQLite is the one locking the db file for write and my only concern here is about Dapper and what it does in such scenario.**

Comment: I got interested about SQLite yesterday and now reading all kinds of info about and I'm also interested how to make it perform well with concurrency. There is mode called WAL that is not enabled by default and should help with concurrentcy https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html
quote from there `WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.`
Entity Framework Core enables WAL by default https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, SQLite implements locking on DB file level.

Dapper or any other full or micro ORM cannot change this fact. No ORM will implement thread management or concurrency for any RDBMS. Thread management is responsibility of user.

Think other way. How ORM will know how to implement threading?

Yes; some ORMs manage connection up to certain level. But mostly, it is only limited to creating/opening/disposing it. ORMs do not control threading or concurrency. It is something to be implemented by user.

**Response to your comment:**

> but yet the question still stays what dapper does in such cases as it may have some sort of retry logic to try execute the query again in case the lock is there

Dapper don't do anything like that. Dapper works exactly (well... almost) like ADO.NET. For any querying part, Dapper is not much functionally different than ADO.NET.

So, to answer your comment, if some provider of ADO.NET implement retry logic, it will be inherited by Dapper automatically. But, Dapper on itself do not implement any such logic.

If I guess correctly, ADO.NET will throw proper exception - Dapper will simply pass on that exception to you.

I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796179/5779732) answer will help you.