# What is the difference between an orm and ADO.net?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm, ado.net

I am reading a book and it says : "if you will create your own data access layer  by using ADO.NET for access into you database, you will be minimally affected whether the data schema exists or not. If however you are using an O/RM, your flexibility will be limited by the tool you use".
What is the major difference between ADO.NET and any other ORM?

Comment: And MS wonders why people don't trust certifications. That statement means that you can write raw SQL queries inside your code even if the database doesn't exist. It's just a string that can't be checked or verified. If anyone works like this, he should *not* be allowed to take that exam

Comment: Link to the guilty [book](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780735677227/samplepages/9780735677227.pdf). Exam Ref 70-486 Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can also create an adapter pattern so that you can use both. It's an extra step, but might save you heartache later.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ADO.NET provides consistent access to data sources such as SQL Server
>   and XML, and to data sources exposed through OLE DB and ODBC.
>   Data-sharing consumer applications can use ADO.NET to connect to these
>   data sources and retrieve, handle, and update the data that they
>   contain.
>
> ADO.NET separates data access from data manipulation into discrete
>   components that can be used separately or in tandem. ADO.NET includes
>   .NET Framework data providers for connecting to a database, executing
>   commands, and retrieving results. Those results are either processed
>   directly, placed in an ADO.NET DataSet object in order to be exposed
>   to the user in an ad hoc manner, combined with data from multiple
>   sources, or passed between tiers. The DataSet object can also be used
>   independently of a .NET Framework data provider to manage data local
>   to the application or sourced from XML.

ADO.NET is a layer that allows you to connect to DB and modify it using SQL connections, commands, parameters. [ADO.NET MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping tool) in
>   computer science is a programming technique for converting data
>   between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming
>   languages. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that
>   can be used from within the programming language. There are both free
>   and commercial packages available that perform object-relational
>   mapping, although some programmers opt to construct their own ORM
>   tools.

`Entity Framework` and `NHibernate` are ORMs. It means that you do not operate by SQL connections, commands, parameters - ORM does it for you and it allows to map your database structure in OOP manner: you can add, read, update, delete records in your DB using objects in C#. You need only map your object to DB correctly. `Entity Framework` is built on ADO.NET and it uses ADO.NET inside. SQL statements are generated by ORM. [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Generally, access to DB without ORM is faster, but you should provide more lines of code. If you want to operate your DB in OOP manner and write more readable code you should choose ORM. It depends on your purposes on what to choose.

There are Micro ORMs (Dapper, BLToolkit) which allows you to write SQL queries and map parameters to object properties. Micro ORMs, in general, have better performance than Full ORMs, but ADO.NET is still faster.

Also, there are some questions and answers on StackOverflow: [EF vs ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328889/entityframework-vs-pure-ado-net)

Answer (score 9):

- Along the way, I have learned that developers hate working with `DataSets` and `DataReaders`
- **.NET** platform defines a number of namespaces that allow you to
  interact with relational database systems. Collectively speaking,
  these namespaces are known as `ADO.NET.`
- **ORM** stands for `Object-Relational Mapper`  which is to map an object with a relational world. As the name suggests it `builds a relation / maps objects (model) to database objects(tables).`
- `ADO.NET` was the traditional way to connect your application to a database & gave the developer entire control over the database operations whereas `ORM` is built on top of `ADO.NET` and uses `ADO.NET` implicitly.
- In short using an ORM like **NHibernate, Entity Framework** makes life simpler where mapping of objects(models) is taken care of internally by the `ORM.`
- When you use an `ORM` not everything is in your hands since all of the queries are generated by the `ORM` itself. Now we don't know whether those queries are *optimized* or not.

> In scenarios where performance of your application is a primary concern & absolutely critical **OR** in scenarios where you know that your application will grow huge in mere future then it is advisable to use `ADO.NET` rather than `Entity Framework` because it makes your application heavy.

- The solution to this was `Micro ORM's` like **Dapper, BLToolkit**. These provide the esssence of what developers want - an easy way to map Database operations to strongly typed classes.
- LINQ support in some makes it even better.But the main advantage of some of these Micro-ORMs is its `raw speed.`

### Words of Wisdom:

1. `Dapper` just does mapping but you need to code a lot , `EF` does much more on the top of it and not just mapping. So EF will be slow.
2. I can also say that pure `ADO.NET` is faster than `Dapper` , `OLEDB` is faster than `ADO.NET` and `ODBC` can be faster than `OLEDB.`
3. So if I am serious about performance I would probably *avoid* any `ORM.`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can also create an adapter pattern so that you can use both. It's an extra step, but might save you heartache later. Do you have any input on this?